# How to select a column according to row max value

Tags: r, database, dataframe, tidyverse, reshape

I need help with a data extraction problem. I have a data frame and I need to build another according to the first one:

[Data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ESudMr1h47a5-ybrrqnXQs9LwSs17tmk?usp=sharing)

I would like to have in my new data set 3 columns. The first one has to have the values from 2000 to 2020 for those individuals (columns) with max values in row "means".  The second column has to have something I write in each row and the third column have got to have the title of that column chosen before as the one with the max mean value. Then the result has to look like this for this case:

[image: picture]

It would be great if you could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)

res <- cmk %>%
  transmute(Industrials, 
            category = row_number(), 
            subcategory = 'Industrials')
res

#   Industrials category subcategory
#1     1.263835        1 Industrials
#2     1.264464        2 Industrials
#3     1.305693        3 Industrials
#4     1.313662        4 Industrials
#5     1.336979        5 Industrials
#6     1.279066        6 Industrials
#7     1.205527        7 Industrials
#8     1.161275        8 Industrials
#...
#...
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak. However, the code is not working as I would like because I would like to have in the first column (value) the values of one column of cmk selected because of having the max value in row "mean". In this case, I should obtain values for column "industrials" and the third column should have only industrials as shown in the graph of the question.

Comment: @LMLP See the updated answer. Is that what you want?